# Grant select on views which use functions

Tags: function, postgresql, select, view, sql-grant

I'm using postgresql 8.4 and am having a bit of a problem granting select privileges on a view from a database onwed by a different user when the view uses any of the databases functions.

As the new user, when I try to run, for example **select * from users_pwd;** where users_pwd is defined as:

```
create view users_pwd as
select *, get_pwd(id)
from users;
```

and get_pwd as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_pwd(p_id integer)
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
declare u record;
BEGIN
select into u * from users where id = p_id;
return u.password;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation users
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "select * from users where id =  $1 "
PL/pgSQL function "get_pwd" line 3 at SQL statement
```

The only way to have the user query the view is to explicitly grant select on the table **users** which I don't want to do.

If a view doesn't use any function, but rather just other tables which the new user doesn't have explicit access to it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create the function with owner who can select from the table users. Such a function should be created with SECURITY DEFINER clause, so it will be executed with the owner rights.

More information you can find here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-createfunction.html

You can also GRANT EXECUTE privileges on functions. See [GRANT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-grant.html) in the docs.